# how to import classes from one module and initialise and run it in django

Tags: python, django

How to import classes from all .py in a module with same structure and run by iterating over it. For Example,

module_one:

```
script_a:
    class A:
        def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            code here
        def run(self,**kwargs):
            code here
        def finish(self,**kwargs):
            code here
script_b:
    class B:
        def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            code here
        def run(self,**kwargs):
            code here
        def finish(self,**kwargs):
            code here
and so on ...
```

module_two:

```
script:
    class Run:
        def run_all(self,**kwargs):
            for class in classes_from_module_one:
                c = class()
                c.run()
                c.finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that [module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) refers to python file, while to what you refer as module is usually called a package.

Now, for your problem, you could use some mixture of utilities found in [pkgutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html), [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html), and [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) or simple `dir()`. For example, using `walk_modules` and `get_members`:

```
# pack/mod_a.py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        print("A run!")

    def finish(self):
        print("A finished!")

# pack/mod_b.py
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        print("B run!")

    def finish(self):
        print("B finished!")

# all.py
from importlib import import_module
from inspect import getmembers
from pkgutil import iter_modules


class Run:
    def run_all(self, **kwargs):
        modules = iter_modules(["pack"])
        for module in modules:
            members = getmembers(import_module(f"pack.{module[1]}"))
            my_classes = [member for name, member in members if not name.startswith("_")]
            for cls in my_classes:
                c = cls()
                c.run()
                c.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run = Run()
    run.run_all()
```

The output is:

```
A run!
A finished!
B run!
B finished!
```

However for this solution you have to note, that `getmembers` will return all members of module - including built-ins, and *imported entities to the modules* - so you will have to implement your own check to properly filter-out those unwanted (see simple `startswith` in my example).